Is there a way to check the NATIVE partition column on a table in Postgres v16+
I have been trying to find a way to get this from a sql script to no avail. I have been looking at the schema information tables but I just can't find anything that would tell me if a table has this PARTITION BY, or rather, it was created with it, as it is my understanding currently the ALTER TABLE ... PARTITION BY... is not an option.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
I tried looking at the schema information tables
I am using native partition, as opposed to the inherit in old postgres version
